# UIStackView goes wild stacking items at one spot

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistackview

[image: stack view problem]

I just created this stack view with labels and 2 views to hold text a bit differently(Pick up Date, Pick up time etc). There is no code touching the controller. There are no constraint errors and everything seems to look fine in Interface Builder but when I run it as you can see every item is in one spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that this layout problems were caused by `wC hAny` parameter checked in every single view by default.

[image: was]

**So the solution was to delete it by pressing cross icon near it and to check `Installed`**

[image: should be]